# Installing Intel HAXM inside VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, vt-x, intel-haxm

I'm trying to install Intel Hardware Acceleration Execution Manager in a Windows 7 guest using VirtualBox.

When I run `intelhaxm.exe` to install it, I get the following error:

[image]

This isn't true, because my Windows guest is running with VT-X/AMD-V enabled, and my host machine supports is an Intel CPU with VT-X support.

How can I install this in my Windows guest machine?

Comment: Look up "nested virtualization".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want nested virtualization with **VT-x exposed to guest** operating system.

It is possible on VMware since version 8 or 9 (I'm not sure about 8, if someone knows please post comment), but it **seems to be not supported in VirtualBox** (according to this still open feature request: [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032)).

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Btw... why you need that?

Comment: Because I was going to develop an app using Apache Cordova/Phone Gap for Android, and if I neeed to use the x86 emulator, it requires that Intel driver which also requires VT-X...